# New civiEvent template URL redirecting to Events Template page

Tags: civievent

In civiCRM 5.59.3 on Drupal 9, I'm trying to create a custom civiEvent template. I've gone through all the tabs and at the bottom of Info and Settings there is a unique URL. However, this URL is being redirected to the Events Templates page.

Where is this happening and how do I correct it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the unique URL there should go anywhere (it shouldn't really be there at all). You can't register for an event template, only an event itself. You have to create an event from the event template and then the URL for that event will work.

Comment: Here's a change to fix this in future versions: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/26419
If you're able, you could review it on the test site there and verify it does what it should (ask for help if you need it).

Answer (score 0):

My bad. I had not yet created an event from this new template. Once I did that, it worked.